# AWS S3 Lambda Trigger Not Working When Uploaded to Bucket Subfolder

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda Python function that will resize images on upload.

Everything is working correctly, but only when I upload directly to the `bucket`. When I upload files to the `bucket/uploads/` folder, it would no longer trigger the resize function.

I have tried the filtering options in the trigger settings `uploads/` to no avail.

Is the `Create Trigger > S3` option only available for the main bucket?

Here is my Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event["Records"]:
        bucket = record["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        key = record["s3"]["object"]["key"]
        download_path = "/tmp/{}{}".format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path = "/tmp/resized-{}".format(key)
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
```

Comment: How do you know that it's not executing? Via absence of CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda invocation or via lack of resized file? And what is the configuration of your S3 event trigger?

Comment: "Assuming it is related to my Lambda function" Please don't make assumptions. Look at the AWS Lambda function logs and see what the actual issue is.

Comment: @jarmod - correct, no CloudWatch logs as the Lambda is not even being invoked when the file is uploaded to the subfolder. And since it is not running, no resized images either.

Comment: @MarkB - Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the lambda logs are not available as the function is not even being triggered when the file is uploaded to a subfolder.

Comment: So how would you expect the problem to be with your Lambda function, if the function isn't being invoked? Your assumption that "it is related to my Lambda function" appears to be entirely incorrect. You should probably include details about your S3 trigger configuration.

Comment: Not a lot to go on here, absent the trigger config, but make sure that you're using `s3:ObjectCreated:*` as it covers all possible forms of upload. Also your code doesn't appear to include the resize/upload function but I presume they exist and you simply haven't included them.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as you.

To fix this, make sure that the prefix is similar to this format: **folder/sub-folder**.

There shouldn't be a forward slash / at the beginning and at the end of the prefix.